# How to implement onBackPressed() & intents in fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I know that onBackPressed() is a method in activity but, I want to use the functionality in fragments such that when back button is pressed, it gets redirected to another activity via Intent. Is there any solution to this ?

```
public class News_Events_fragment extends Fragment {
ProgressDialog pd;
ListView lv1;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
int NotiCount;
TextView txt_title, txt_msg, textView;
Context context;
Intent intent ;
ArrayList<SliderMsgTitleModel> CurrentOfficersPastList;
NewsActivityAdapter pastAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = (Context) getActivity();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news, container, false);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<SliderMsgTitleModel>>() {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pd.setCancelable(true);
            pd.setTitle("UPOA");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait,loading the data...");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<SliderMsgTitleModel> doInBackground(
                Void... params) {
            System.out.println("In Background");
            CurrentOfficersPastList = new ArrayList<SliderMsgTitleModel>();
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("message");
            query.whereEqualTo("featured_status", true);
            // query.whereEqualTo("push_status", true);

            query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");

            query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("title"));
            query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("message"));
            try {
                query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
                List<ParseObject> results = query.find();
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    ParseObject object = results.get(i);
                    CurrentOfficersPastList.add(new SliderMsgTitleModel(
                            object.getString("title"), object
                                    .getString("message")));
                    System.out.println("title is=="
                            + object.getString("title") + "&& message is"
                            + object.getString("message") + "size is"
                            + CurrentOfficersPastList.size());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
            pd.dismiss();

            return CurrentOfficersPastList;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SliderMsgTitleModel> value) {

            pd.dismiss();
            /*Intent ent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsActivity.class);
            ent.putExtra("NEWSLIST", (ArrayList<SliderMsgTitleModel>) value);
            startActivity(ent);
            System.out.println("Value is" + value.size());*/

            CurrentOfficersPastList = new ArrayList<SliderMsgTitleModel>();
            CurrentOfficersPastList = value;
            lv1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_title);
            pastAdapter = new NewsActivityAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_news_txt, CurrentOfficersPastList);
            lv1.setAdapter(pastAdapter);

        }
    }.execute();

    return rootView;
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onBackPressed();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click",2000).show();
            String cameback="CameBack";
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Comingback", cameback);
            startActivity(intent);
}

 }
```

Comment: Is your problem get solved?? I edited my post. Please visit sample app created on github for back stack of fragment.

Comment: same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132623/onback-pressed-not-showing-data-in-fragments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override onKeyDown instead of onBackPressed. Not necessarily . But this works for me

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                String cameback="CameBack";
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HomeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Comingback", cameback);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true
    }
            return false;
}
```

Comment: Its an integer representing whick Key was pressed by user.

Comment: @AlokKulkarni can you tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132623/onback-pressed-not-showing-data-in-fragments

Answer (score 39):

You can interact with the fragment using a callback interface. In your activity add the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener;

    public interface OnBackPressedListener {
        void doBack();
    }

    public void setOnBackPressedListener(OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener) {
        this.onBackPressedListener = onBackPressedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (onBackPressedListener != null)
            onBackPressedListener.doBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        onBackPressedListener = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

In your fragment add the following:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyActivity.OnBackPressedListener {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
         ((MyActivity) getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void doBack() {
        //BackPressed in activity will call this;
    }

}
```

Comment: How does this not have more up votes? I have been searching for this answer for days. TY and ++;

Comment: I think the problem is with the following line in the fragment:
"((MyActivity) getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(this);"
The "MyActivity" tightly couples your activity and fragment. Or in other words, your fragments become tied to the activity which is IMO contrary to the intent of fragments (supposed to be modular).

Comment: The listener needs to be set back to null as well, otherwise the it will crash for the remaining fragments in the stack : 
override fun onDestroy() {
        (activity as MyActivity)?. onBackPressedListener = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

Answer (score 9):

Yes, There is. You should implement like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragment != null)
        //user defined onBackPressed method. Not of Fragment.
        fragment.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        //this will pass BackPress event to activity. If not called, it will
        //prevent activity to get BackPress event.
        super.onBackPressed();
    }   
}
```

**Explanation**

1. Check whether your fragment is initialized or not. If it is, then pass on back press event to your fragment.
2. If above condition not passed, just pass back press to your activity so that it will handle it.

**Note**

Here condition can be anything. I just take `fragment` initialization as an example. May be that can't be helped you. You need to define your own condition to pass it to fragment.

### Edit

I created a sample application on GitHub to implement Back Stack of fragment .

Download [Fragment Back Stack](https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack) application.

Comment: need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132623/onback-pressed-not-showing-data-in-fragments

Answer (score 1):

You can implement onKeyListener for your fragment and call next activity within that.
I've never tried this. But i hope it may help

For Example

```
fragmentObject.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {  
            //your code here


        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

Answer (score -10):

You need to override onBackPressed method in fragment.

Comment: it asking me to remove annotation :(

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html .. There is no `onBackPressed` method in Fragment.

Comment: OnBackPressed is located in an Activity