# setActivityForResult from Fragment returns null data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a Fragment `MainFragment` and I do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PersonActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

The activity starts ok and it starts its own `PersonFragment` and inside the `PersonFragment` I do:

```
@Override
 public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.putExtra(PERSON_ID_EXTRA, getPersonId());
      i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PERSON_CONTACT_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) contactFriends);
      getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
}
```

Back in my `MainFragment` I do:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ( requestCode != 0) {
            return;
        }
        int personId = data.getIntExtra(PERSON_ID_EXTRA, -1);
        List<Person> contacts = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(PERSON_CONTACT_LIST);
        for(Person p:contacts) {
            Log.d("APP", p.getFullName());
        }
}
```

I see that the code goes to `onActivityResult` but the `data` is null. What am I messing up here?

**Update:**
I see that pressing back button does not call `onDestroy()`.
But where am all examples I saw used `getActivity.finish()` and I don't want to finish the activity. Only when the user presses e.g. back send the data

**Update2:**
I added the following and I go through that code but the `Intent data` in the result `onActivityResult` is still null

```
@Override
 public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.putExtra(PERSON_ID_EXTRA, getPersonId());
      i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PERSON_CONTACT_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) contactFriends);
      getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
}
```

Comment: override `onKeyDown` instead of using `onDestroy()`

Comment: @Apurva:I will try that but also please check update in OP

Comment: @Apurva:`onKeyDown` is activity method. I am setting the result in the fragment. How am I supposed to use it?

Comment: I also know that but I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-intents-in-fragment

Comment: If you want to use the startActivityForResult in your fragment don't forget to put a return false in your startActivityForResult in your FragmentActivity class. This one is prior to the fragment one. Hope that's helps

Comment: @vincent091:Which activity are you talking about? The hosting activity of the fragment that startActivityForResult or the hosting activity of the fragment that is being started?

Comment: @Jim Are you getting resultCode as RESULT_CANCELED?

Comment: @ArunKumar:I see in the debugger `0,0,null` as the arguments passed to `onActivityResult`. So yes

Comment: @ArunKumar:Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `Activity` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) about `finish`:

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The
>   ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) about `onActivityResult`:

> Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode
>   you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional
>   data from it.

So, `onActivityResult` will only be called when the second activity finishes.

If you don't want to `finish` your `PersonActivity` to send the result to your main activity, then you may want to start another intent to send the data or pass the data using static fields (not a best practice at all).

In your case, to set your result when you press the back button, you can write a code like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra(PERSON_ID_EXTRA, getPersonId());
            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PERSON_CONTACT_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) contactFriends);
            getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Follow up based on the comments:

The code for the `finish()` on the `Activity` class looks as follows:

```
// Call this when your activity is done
// and should be closed. The ActivityResult
// is propagated back to whoever launched
// you via onActivityResult().
public void finish() {
    if (mParent == null) {
        int resultCode;
        Intent resultData;
        synchronized (this) {
            resultCode = mResultCode;
            resultData = mResultData;
        }
        if (false) Log.v(TAG, "Finishing self: token=" + mToken);
        try {
            if (resultData != null) {
                resultData.prepareToLeaveProcess();
            }
            if (ActivityManagerNative.getDefault()
                .finishActivity(mToken, resultCode, resultData)) {
                mFinished = true;
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Empty
        }
    } else {
        mParent.finishFromChild(this);
    }
}
```

Here you can see that is the responsibility for setting the result values  lays on the `finish()` method.

Then, before the `Activity` is destroyed, the `onDestroy()` method is called. That is the reason why setting the result of the `Activity` on the `onDestroy()` method won't work.

Comment: `start another intent to send the data`: What do you mean by this?

Comment: `So, onActivityResult will only be called when the second activity finishes.` But I see that it is called after `onPause` as well

Comment: @Jim I mean that you can create a `new Intent`, and start it with extras to send the data

Comment: @Jim I have made a test and in my case `onActivityResult` is not called after `onPause`. I will make another quick test to double check

Comment: But don't I create the a new Intent already? I am sorry, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I press the back button and the `onActivityResult` is called. Where am I supposed to add the code `getActivity().setResult()`?

Comment: @Jim You can add your `setResult()` in an event (pressing a `Button`, onKeyDown, ...) but after that, and according to the documentation you should call `finish()`. In your case if you want to set your result when the back button is pressed you would need to do it on the `onKeyDown`. I will update my answer to show the code

Comment: But the method `onActivityResult` is called without calling `finish()`, it is just that the `Intent data` is  `null` and the status is `CANCELLED`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73600/discussion-between-antonio-and-jim).

Comment: By the way, I should put that snippet in onPause and onDestroy?

Comment: @Jim no, onKeyDown is a función of Activity. onPause and onDestroy will not call finish and hence will not set your result unless you explicitly call finish before

Comment: Does it make sense to override `onPause` and `onDestroy` to call `finish()` there to get the result?

Comment: @Jim no, when you call finish the activity finishes and then onDestroy is called, but the result is set first, so if you call finish and set your result on the onDestroy you will get an empty result