# How to make WebView inside fragment to go back to previous tab?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-viewpager

I have a fragment which contains a webview.And the fragment is reused in all the four pages of a viewPager.What i want is, when the user clicks the back button i want the webView Fragment to go back to the previous tab of the current webViewFragment.And finally exit the activity.I can easily do this if the webView was inside an activity like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebview.canGoBack())
            mWebview.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

But i cannot do this in a fragment because the fragment cannot override onBackPressed().How can i do this inside a fragment which is inside a viewPager

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-intents-in-fragment

Comment: you can use an interface and implement it in activity and call it from fragment , call this interface from fragment.

Comment: why don't you override onBackPressed in activity and call setCurrentItem() in there if there is a previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `setOnKeyListener` on webview to handle back button.

```
mWebview.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebview.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebview.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

If there is no previous page in your webview then it will trigger usual `onBackPressed`.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfect for fragment webview backpress.

You can implement `setOnKeyListener` on webview to handle back button

```
mWebview.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && mWebview.canGoBack())
        {
            mWebview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```